# Only "propose/suggest" doing actions you yourself will be involved in

Tags: ing, catenative-verbs

*Is That What you Mean* reads

> If someone **suggest**s do**ing** something, it means that the speaker is one
> of the people who will do it.

*Collins Cobuild Usage* reads

[image]

Is this a general pattern? What other verbs, apart from reporting ones such as *advise*, or *recommend*, behave likewise with present participle?

Comment: I'm skeptical of the premise. What's this source?

Comment: @AndyBonner At least two: _Collins Cobuild English Usage_ and _Is that what you mean?_

Comment: I'm intrigued, but you might want to edit to ask more of a "how/why" question rather than one where the answer is simply a list. Looking forward to answers!

Comment: I can think of at least five off the top of  my head, but we don't do lists.

Comment: @DjinTonic only reporting ones?

Comment: This is a joke, not a real truism. And it's certainly not a language issue, it's more about human behavior.

Comment: What pattern are you referring to?  The pattern where the speaker is necessarily involved if he uses the present participle after a verb?  None of advise, recommend or suggest fit this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about a false syntactic principle that was only created for the sake of a joke double-entendre context.

Comment: Still not sure what pattern you mean - are you referring to verbs that simply get followed by a gerund?  e.g. I like skiing?

Comment: I guess no one here has actually taught English. These verbs are always given as ones  where you can't use **to**, for example. The usage is: I recommend *you go*  (notice that) **Or** I recommend going now. The example from  Is That What You Mean show corrects grammar {suggest doing) but is an untrue statement.

Answer (score 1):

This seems another 'rule' that is broken so commonly it smacks of baseless prescriptivism.

> Confronted with a case involving a clattering air conditioner, Cosimo
> Caccavari, the city's top acoustician, asked the owner to draw a floor
> plan of his house. Then Caccavari **suggested moving the air
> conditioner to another location where it would not face any near
> neighbor**. (Time Magazine: 1971/10/11)
>
> The couple, both 46, consulted Denver financial planner Scott Wiley,
> who **suggested switching to index funds**. (15 minute retirement
> plan; Money: Apr 2004)
>
> For help, you may want to consider taking a calcium supplement.
> Researchers at Columbia University found that women who took 1,200 mg
> of calcium per day noticed a 48% decrease in PMS symptoms. Tracy W.
> Gaudet, MD, director of the Duke Center for Integrative Medicine,
> **suggests taking 400 mg doses two or three times a day**. (Prevention: Oct2005: Vol. 57)
>
> Your father applied for Veterans Affairs financial assistance, but
> transferred homes and bank accounts into your name and, more
> concerning, has $120,000 stashed away in a safety deposit box. You
> should check with a legal counsel to ensure that you're not helping
> your father hide assets from the VA, if he is now receiving
> assistance. # That said, I don't **advise giving your sister a house
> because you feel guilty (or she makes you feel guilty)**. It won't
> repair the relationship between you and your sister and it won't
> change history, or how she feels about your father. (MarketWatch 2017;
> The Moneyologist: My sister, who never helped our father, wants half
> ...)
>
> I've been reassessing my position on various fairy tales lately, your
> Majesty. Sparhawk destroyed Azash with Bhelliom -- just by touching it
> to him. I don't **advise putting your hands on it**, my Emperor.
> You've shown some promise in the past few months, and we'd sort of
> hate to lose you at this point. (The Shining Ones; David Eddings; New
> York: Ballantine Books 1993)
>
> Chin also **advised building a Web site that has your resume and links
> to clips**, to demonstrate Web-savviness to prospective employers.
> (San Francisco Chronicle; Dan Fost; 2000)
>
> Recent research hasn't been able to duplicate this interaction, yet it
> hasn't been proven false either. Experts **advise erring on the side
> of caution**. If you're on hormonal birth control and your doctor
> writes you an Rx for any antibiotic, such as tetracycline, use a
> backup contraceptive while you take the meds and for seven days
> afterward. (Cosmopolitan 2011; Dangerous Combinations; Jessica Levine)
>
> The judge kicked the shards of the broken vase at his feet, scattering
> them and rose petals across the floor. " Bullshit advice for a dying
> man! If you can't do anything more than offer me some crap platitudes,
> I'm checking out of here. I'd rather die in my own home than wait to
> die in a hospital. " # Chandler shrugged. " I don't **advise
> leaving**, but if you want to be discharged, the decision is yours, "
> he said.  (Saturday Evening Post: Sep/Oct2002; STOLEN HEARTS; Zipes,
> Joan, Zipes, Doug)

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* notes (on p1232-1233) that the following verbs taking a gerund-participial complement (-ing clause) have a non-syntactic interpretation of the missing subject:

> *advise, encourage, recommend*
>
> *advocate, deplore, deprecate, discourage, facilitate, fancy, include, involve, justify, mean, necessitate, oppose, save, suggest, support,
> understand*

with the following having subject control:

> *forget, recollect, remember, report*
>
> *abhor, anticipate, appreciate, begrudge, can help, celebrate, chance, contemplate, countenance, defer, delay, describe, detest, discuss,
> dislike, dread, endure, enjoy, envisage, fancy, foresee, imagine,
> mention, mind, miss, put off, risk, recall, tolerate, relish, resent,
> regret, welcome*

The difference being exemplified by the following.

> *I wouldn’t recommend buying it*. [potential buyer unspecified]
>
> vs
>
> *I remember buying it*. [buyer = speaker]

The only verb in the list given in the question that does seems to have subject control is 'propose'. I was unable to find any instance of it used with an understood subject that did not include the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that you only propose **doing actions*** that you yourself will be involved in. *Daisy proposed moving to New York.*

-- "The London office was generally a pleasant place to work, except for John who was an arsehole and always had been. When John announced that he was thinking of moving house, *Daisy proposed/suggested/urged/recommended, etc., moving to New York.”*

In *Daisy proposed/suggested/urged/recommended, etc., moving to New York.* - *moving to New York.* is the object and phrasal (gerundive * ) equivalent of a content clause – “that I/they/he/we, etc., move to New York” – and entirely dependent upon the context, not the form.

As the subject of “move to New York” can be anyone or anything, the Cobuild’s advice is suspect to say the least.

The example is even worse, as "to move" is ambitransitive:
"Daisy moved to New York" - she changed houses
"Daisy moved the detention centre to New York" - she had some hand in the relocation of the detention centre. Although if she merely proposed/suggested/urged/recommended, etc., then the chances are that she had no hand in it whatsoever - someone else's job.

The questions then becomes, “*Can content clauses only be self-referential?*” and *"Can all content clauses be replaced by gerundive phrases?*" The answer has to be “No,” in both cases.

*The phrase “**doing actions**” is virtually the definition of “gerund”.